# Is there any good and free Date AND Time Picker available for Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, datepicker, datetimepicker

Is there any good and free Date AND Time Picker available for Java Swing?

There are a lot date pickers available but no date AND time picker. This is the closest I came across so far: [Looking for a date AND time picker](http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?t=15566)

Anybody?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

For a time picker you can use a JSpinner and set a JSpinner.DateEditor that only shows the time value.

```
JSpinner timeSpinner = new JSpinner( new SpinnerDateModel() );
JSpinner.DateEditor timeEditor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(timeSpinner, "HH:mm:ss");
timeSpinner.setEditor(timeEditor);
timeSpinner.setValue(new Date()); // will only show the current time
```

Comment: wow so simple and good! Thanks your are great!

Comment: You may also want to use a library such as JDatePicker: http://jdatepicker.org in conjunction to select the date.

Comment: The [LGoodDatePicker](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker) library includes a good **DateTimePicker component**. (As well as the individual DatePicker and TimePicker classes). The three components are simple and easy to use. Here are some screenshots of the components and the demo application. [Screenshot 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ghDdI.png), [Screenshot 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QXgWE.png). The project home page is located at https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker .

Comment: JSpinners are, IMO, ugly and hard to work with. [lbalazscs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10820090/2225787) gives a much more visually appealing picker if you want both date and time.

Answer (score 16):

You can extend the swingx JXDatePicker component:

> "JXDatePicker only handles dates without time. Quite often we need to let the user choose a date and a time. This is an example of how to make use JXDatePicker to handle date and time together."

http://wiki.java.net/twiki/bin/view/Javadesktop/JXDateTimePicker

EDIT: This article disappeared from the web, but as SingleShot discovered, it is still available in an internet archive. Just to be sure, here is the full working example:

```
import org.jdesktop.swingx.calendar.SingleDaySelectionModel;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory;
import javax.swing.text.DateFormatter;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * This is licensed under LGPL.  License can be found here:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.txt
 *
 * This is provided as is.  If you have questions please direct them to charlie.hubbard at gmail dot you know what.
 */
public class DateTimePicker extends JXDatePicker {
    private JSpinner timeSpinner;
    private JPanel timePanel;
    private DateFormat timeFormat;

    public DateTimePicker() {
        super();
        getMonthView().setSelectionModel(new SingleDaySelectionModel());
    }

    public DateTimePicker( Date d ) {
        this();
        setDate(d);
    }

    public void commitEdit() throws ParseException {
        commitTime();
        super.commitEdit();
    }

    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setTimeSpinners();
    }

    @Override
    public JPanel getLinkPanel() {
        super.getLinkPanel();
        if( timePanel == null ) {
            timePanel = createTimePanel();
        }
        setTimeSpinners();
        return timePanel;
    }

    private JPanel createTimePanel() {
        JPanel newPanel = new JPanel();
        newPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        //newPanel.add(panelOriginal);

        SpinnerDateModel dateModel = new SpinnerDateModel();
        timeSpinner = new JSpinner(dateModel);
        if( timeFormat == null ) timeFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance( DateFormat.SHORT );
        updateTextFieldFormat();
        newPanel.add(new JLabel( "Time:" ) );
        newPanel.add(timeSpinner);
        newPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        return newPanel;
    }

    private void updateTextFieldFormat() {
        if( timeSpinner == null ) return;
        JFormattedTextField tf = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) timeSpinner.getEditor()).getTextField();
        DefaultFormatterFactory factory = (DefaultFormatterFactory) tf.getFormatterFactory();
        DateFormatter formatter = (DateFormatter) factory.getDefaultFormatter();
        // Change the date format to only show the hours
        formatter.setFormat( timeFormat );
    }

    private void commitTime() {
        Date date = getDate();
        if (date != null) {
            Date time = (Date) timeSpinner.getValue();
            GregorianCalendar timeCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            timeCalendar.setTime( time );

            GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            calendar.setTime(date);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timeCalendar.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY ) );
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timeCalendar.get( Calendar.MINUTE ) );
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
            setDate(newDate);
        }

    }

    private void setTimeSpinners() {
        Date date = getDate();
        if (date != null) {
            timeSpinner.setValue( date );
        }
    }

    public DateFormat getTimeFormat() {
        return timeFormat;
    }

    public void setTimeFormat(DateFormat timeFormat) {
        this.timeFormat = timeFormat;
        updateTextFieldFormat();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Date Time Picker");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        DateTimePicker dateTimePicker = new DateTimePicker();
        dateTimePicker.setFormats( DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance( DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.MEDIUM ) );
        dateTimePicker.setTimeFormat( DateFormat.getTimeInstance( DateFormat.MEDIUM ) );

        dateTimePicker.setDate(date);

        frame.getContentPane().add(dateTimePicker);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This link is now gone, however the [Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/web.php) has it [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20111118105909/http://wiki.java.net/twiki/bin/view/Javadesktop/JXDateTimePicker?TWIKISID=cc05dea1611ad043796cd67ed476d711;skin=print).

Comment: I included now here the full code of this little gem :)

Comment: Is there cell editor, to put it to table cell?

Comment: How can I show the time part in the Text field itself ?

Comment: I got it  just set the format DateTimePicker dp = new DateTimePicker();
  dp.setFormats("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

Answer (score 9):

Use the both combined.. that's what i did:

```
public static JPanel buildDatePanel(String label, Date value) {
JPanel datePanel = new JPanel();

JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
if (value != null) {
    dateChooser.setDate(value);
}
for (Component comp : dateChooser.getComponents()) {
    if (comp instanceof JTextField) {
    ((JTextField) comp).setColumns(50);
    ((JTextField) comp).setEditable(false);
    }
}

datePanel.add(dateChooser);

SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerDateModel();
JSpinner timeSpinner = new JSpinner(model);
JComponent editor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(timeSpinner, "HH:mm:ss");
timeSpinner.setEditor(editor);
if(value != null) {
    timeSpinner.setValue(value);
}

datePanel.add(timeSpinner);

return datePanel;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is the [FLib-JCalendar](http://flib.sourceforge.net/JCalendar/doc/screenshots.html) component with a combined Date and Time Picker.

Answer (score 1):

As you said Date picker is easy, there are many out there.

As for a Time picker, check out how Google Calendar does it when creating a new entry.  It allows you to type in anything while at the same time it has a drop down in 30 mins increments.  The drop down changes when you change the minutes.

If you need to allow the user to pick seconds, then the best you can do is a typable/drop down combo