# Is there any date picker java swing which is easy to use and program?

Tags: java, swing, datepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any good and free Date AND Time Picker available for Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654342/is-there-any-good-and-free-date-and-time-picker-available-for-java-swing)

Is there any date picker java swing which is easy to use and program?
i want the most basic one just pop up and choose the date nothingelse.. Please send me also with a tutorial that how can i use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Professionally we use [JDatePicker](http://www.jdatepicker.com/purchase.html) but you will have to pay for it. there tutorial is [here](http://www.jdatepicker.com/docs/tutorial/index.html).  If you are looking for a lower cost option I'd consider using JIDE's [DateSpinner](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm) you can try it [here](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/1.4/jide_demo.jnlp) and see the source code.  Unfortunately JIDE's component is just a spinner to use the ComboBox or Panel you will need a paid for license.

I should point out that we also use JIDE and JDatePicker we don't receive any royalties

Comment: The LGoodDatePicker library includes a good **DatePicker** component. (As well as the TimePicker and DateTimePicker classes). The three components are simple and easy to use. For a usage example, look at the "BasicDemo.java" class. It's an open source library (free). Here are some screenshots of the components and the full demo. [Screenshot 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ghDdI.png), [Screenshot 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QXgWE.png). The project home page is located at http://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker .

Answer (score 1):

Try [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/index.html). Has quite a bit of functionality pre-built.