# Set step for a DateEditor in a JSpinner

Tags: java, jspinner

How can a *step* be specified for JSpinner? (for example of 10 minutes instead of 1)

There is a model that allow select step size for numbers

```
SpinnerNumberModel(value, min, max, step);
```

but how to set it for Dates?

This code

```
JSpinner timeSpinner = new JSpinner( new SpinnerDateModel() );
DateEditor timeEditor = new DateEditor(timeSpinner, "HH:mm:ss");
timeSpinner.setEditor(timeEditor);
timeSpinner.setValue(new Date()); // will only show the current time
```

(From this answer [Is there any good and free Date AND Time Picker available for Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654342/is-there-any-good-and-free-date-and-time-picker-available-for-java-swing))

Allows edit time only, but the steps are always 1 hour, 1 minute, or 1 second depending on if "HH", "HH:mm", or "HH:mm:ss" is specified.

---

Is there any simple way to have min, max, and step for minutes?

Thanks

Comment: well a `Date` can easily been converted to `long` using `getTime()`, from where you can add you login in increment of Time in `milliseconds` and convert back it into a `Date` at printing time..

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateEditor.getModel()` to get the [`SpinnerDateModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerDateModel.html) which provides `setStart`,`setEnd` and `setCalendarField`.

Comment: "The value of the calendarField property must be one of the java.util.Calendar constants that specify a field within a Calendar", then it's not possible to assign a 10 minutes step because TEN_MINUTES is not a constant from Calendar

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the code of `SpinnerDateModel`:

```
public Object getNextValue() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //Current date.
    cal.setTime(value.getTime()); //Set the date to the current value of the model.
    cal.add(calendarField, 1); //Increment the date by 1 unit of the selected calendar field (e.g. 1 month).
    Date next = cal.getTime(); //Convert back to Date Object.
    return ((end == null) || (end.compareTo(next) >= 0)) ? next : null;
}

public Object getPreviousValue() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //Current date.
    cal.setTime(value.getTime()); //Set the date to the current value of the model.
    cal.add(calendarField, -1); //Decrement the date by 1 unit of the selected calendar field (e.g. 1 month).
    Date prev = cal.getTime(); //Convert back to Date Object.
    return ((start == null) || (start.compareTo(prev) <= 0)) ? prev : null;
}
```

It works with adding or substracting 1 unit of the specified calendar field.
You want to customize this number 1 to something else.
So I see two options here:

1. Reimplement `AbstractSpinnerModel`. Just copy-paste `SpinnerDateModel` (it's NOT big), then introduce your integer field "step" for example, and instead of the number 1, just put "step" in `getNext` and `getPrevious`.
2. Implement a `SpinnerDateModel`, which also works internally with a `SpinnerDateModel`. It's going to be a lot smaller, but is a bit hackish I guess.

Follows the code of such an `SpinnerDateModel` (case 2):

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;

public class MultiStepDateSpinner extends JPanel {
    private static class StepperSpinnerDateModel extends SpinnerDateModel {
        private final SpinnerDateModel internal; //We let the internal SpinnerDateModel do the work for us.
        private final int step; //The number of steps to increment and decrement per click.
        private Object currentValue; //Needed to get restored each time getPreviousValue and getNextValue is called.

        private StepperSpinnerDateModel(final Date value, final Comparable start, final Comparable end, final int calendarField, final int step) {
            internal = new SpinnerDateModel(value, start, end, calendarField);
            if (step <= 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non positive step.");
            this.step = step;
            currentValue = internal.getValue();
        }

        private StepperSpinnerDateModel(final int step) {
            this(new Date(), null, null, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, step);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValue() {
            return currentValue;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(final Object value) {
            internal.setValue(value);
            currentValue = value;
            fireStateChanged(); //Important step for the spinner to get updated each time the model's value changes.
        }

        @Override
        public Object getNextValue() {
            Object next = null;
            for (int i=0; i<step; ++i) { //Calculate step next values:
                next = internal.getNextValue();
                internal.setValue(next); //We have to set the next value internally, in order to recalculate the next-next value in the next loop.
            }
            internal.setValue(currentValue); //Restore current value.
            return next;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getPreviousValue() {
            Object prev = null;
            for (int i=0; i<step; ++i) { //Calculate step previous values:
                prev = internal.getPreviousValue();
                internal.setValue(prev); //We have to set the previous value internally, in order to recalculate the previous-previous value in the next loop.
            }
            internal.setValue(currentValue); //Restore current value.
            return prev;
        }
    }

    private MultiStepDateSpinner() {
        super(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        //Increment and decrement by 4 minutes each step.
        //The null values indicate there shall be no minimum nor maximum date.
        //The current value is set to the current date.
        final JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new StepperSpinnerDateModel(new Date(), null, null, Calendar.MINUTE, 4));

        final JButton getValueButton = new JButton("Get value");
        getValueButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, spinner.getValue(), "Got value", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        });

        add(spinner);
        add(getValueButton);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MultiStepDateSpinner());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The example code above, is runnable, so you can see it in practice.

Why not just let it be an `AbstractSpinnerModel` instead of `SpinnerDateModel`? Because we need it to be identified as an instance of `SpinnerDateModel` so the `JSpinner` internally allocates by default a `DateEditor` for the editor.
Even if you extend `AbstractSpinnerModel` and supply the spinner with a `DateEditor`, you will get an exception complaining about the model not being a `SpinnerDateModel`.

The cleanest way though as I see it, is to reimplement `AbstractSpinnerModel` and copy paste the code of `SpinnerDateModel` if needed (which is not big) and introduce any fields you feel.

Answer (score 0):

```
Incrementa JSpinnerDateEditor_15_+_15_minutos
    Calendar Horacalendario = Calendar.getInstance();
    Horacalendario.setTime(cita_hora.getDate());
    Date HoraParaCita = Horacalendario.getTime();//para asignar luego del incremento de 15 formato date()'
    int minutos = Horacalendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    Horacalendario.set(Horacalendario.get(Calendar.YEAR), Horacalendario.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            Horacalendario.get(Calendar.DATE), Horacalendario.get(Calendar.HOUR), 0);//hago cero los minutos
    if (minutos >= 1 & minutos <= 14) {
        Horacalendario.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15); //minutos A Sumar 
        HoraParaCita = Horacalendario.getTime();
        cita_hora.setDate(HoraParaCita);
    }
    if (minutos >= 16 & minutos <= 29) {
        Horacalendario.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        HoraParaCita = Horacalendario.getTime();
        cita_hora.setDate(HoraParaCita);
    }
    if (minutos >= 31 & minutos <= 44) {
        Horacalendario.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
        HoraParaCita = Horacalendario.getTime();
        cita_hora.setDate(HoraParaCita);
    }
    if (minutos >= 46 & minutos <= 59) {
        Horacalendario.set(Horacalendario.get(Calendar.YEAR), Horacalendario.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                Horacalendario.get(Calendar.DATE), Horacalendario.get(Calendar.HOUR), 0);//hago cero los minutos
        HoraParaCita = Horacalendario.getTime();
        cita_hora.setDate(HoraParaCita);
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers are not very helpful.Try to add an explanation of how this solves the question