# JXDatePicker: change year

Tags: java, swing, swingx

With the JXDayPicker it is hard to change a year, as the user has to click 12 times to achieve this. Therefor I have the same problem as [Java Swing JXDatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111943/java-swing-jxdatepicker).

The problem is that I want to stick with SwingX and that I need a solution which only changes one JXDatePicker.

Thus the proposed solution:

```
UIManager.put(CalendarHeaderHandler.uiControllerID, SpinningCalendarHeaderHandler.class.getName());
datePicker = new JXDatePicker();
datePicker.getMonthView().setZoomable(true); //this is needed for custom header
```

does not work for me.
I also took a look at the MonthViewExtDemo class of the Swinglabs Demo, but I have not figured out what is going on.

Initially I thought it would be as simple as:

```
    JXDatePicker picker = new JXDatePicker();
    JXMonthView monthView = picker.getMonthView();
    monthView.setZoomable(true);
    SpinningCalendarHeaderHandler handler = new SpinningCalendarHeaderHandler();
    handler.install(monthView);
```

But apparently I was wrong.

**Update:**
The requirements were changed a bit, such that every JXDatepicker could use the SpinningCalendarHeaderHandler, but does not have to. Therefor the proposed solution (above) can be used.
I use the following in the beginning of the application:

```
UIManager.put(
    CalendarHeaderHandler.uiControllerID,
    "org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.SpinningCalendarHeaderHandler");
UIManager.put(
    SpinningCalendarHeaderHandler.ARROWS_SURROUND_MONTH,
    Boolean.TRUE);
```

And, later on, for the specific datePicker, which should use the SpinningCalendarHeaderHandler, I use:

```
datePicker.getMonthView().setZoomable(true);
```

This works for the moment, as the zoomable functionality is not implemented yet. But yeah, I think you can call this a hack.

Comment: interesting requirement - per-instance handlers are not supported, if I remember correctly. You might consider filing a feature request in the SwingX issue tracker, if it's halfway easy to implement you might get it in the next release :-)

Comment: The requirements were changed a bit, so that the new header could be used in the whole application. Therefor the isZoomable() defines if the spinning header will be used, or not.