# How to show a calendar when I click a textField with java

Tags: java, textfield

I would like to display a calendar, onto which I would click a text field from which I would choose a date.

After the date is chosen, I would like it - the date - to be inserted again back to this text field where I chose the date from.

Can you help me guys!!
I would like to use `JXDatePicker` for the calendar.

Comment: where did you stuck?

Comment: I am new in java I have no idea how to do it !

Comment: yes but you have to go step by step.first you need to find how to run a code when textfield click event triggered and so on.there are lot of tutorials you can read on internet

Comment: I can handle with textfield event but now I can't find how to show up a calender this is my problem

Comment: this will helps you http://pallandri.blogspot.com/2014/02/java-display-calendar-to-pick-date.html     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111943/java-swing-jxdatepicker