# how to disable future dates using microba datepicker in java?

Tags: java

This is the code of my DatePicker

```
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
datePicker.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy"));
datePicker.getComponent(0).setFont(font);
int height = datePicker.getComponent(0).getPreferredSize().height;
datePicker.getComponent(1).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(height, height));
inputList.add(datePicker);
```

Comment: Your answer should be here.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111943/java-swing-jxdatepicker

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
picker.getMonthView().setUpperBound(new Date().getTime());
```

Comment: getMonthView() is not available in DatePicker class

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the concept of restricted dates:

```
boolean com.michaelbaranov.microba.calendar.VetoPolicy.isRestricted (   Object  source, Calendar    date )
```

This method is used to check if a date is restricted.

Restricted dates can not be selected by users in a control.

Parameters:
source  a control calling this method
date    a date to check. Is never null
Returns:
true if given date is restricted false otherwise

http://sourcecodebrowser.com/libmicroba-java/0.4.4.3/interfacecom_1_1michaelbaranov_1_1microba_1_1calendar_1_1_veto_policy.html