# Sophisticated Calendar for a Swing application

Tags: java, swing, datetime, jar, calendar

I am working on a swing application that requires a date time chooser with a well designed frame.  The time in my application is very vulnerable, and with the jar file that i am using

```
JCalendar.jar
```

The users have faced so many problems while choosing the right time.

So I am asking if there is any other date time chooser that I can use to make it clear and easy for the users to choose the appropriate time.

Answer (score 4):

I had good experiences with JXDatePicker from the [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/) project. With this you can choose a date. If you also need time, see this: [Is there any good and free Date AND Time Picker available for Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654342/is-there-any-good-and-free-date-and-time-picker-available-for-java-swing)

Answer (score 4):

See also this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/665463/230513) using `JSpinner` and a time formatted `DateEditor`. It can be used alongside [`JCalendar`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jcalendar/info).