# date and time picker in swing java

Tags: java, database, swing

I am trying to get user input for date and time by allowing user to choose date and time himself. Then, taking that time and date which he entered , i want to make it to a timesatmp and enter the same in the MS Access Database. 
I know how to do the database part but not how to allow user to pick date and time both(not jdatepicker which just allows date). I also want to know after taking that input how to make a timestamp out of it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654342/is-there-any-good-and-free-date-and-time-picker-available-for-java-swing

Comment: it just allows me to set time ..  i want users to pick date also

Comment: Check _all_ the answers.