# add date & time with calendar

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, calendar

I need to get from the user date and time.
I want that will open a calendar and the user will choose the date & time (like in Microsoft Office).

Is this possible? How can you do it?

example:

[image http://s1.postimg.org/oq6vtfv63/pic.jpg](http://s1.postimg.org/oq6vtfv63/pic.jpg)

Comment: You probably need to google something like "java date time picker". When you will try to create/use one of them and you will have some problems with code come back and ask about these problems. For now it looks like you are asking us to write it for you, or to suggest one of tools/libraries. Both these requests are off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks! @Pshemo.
what about the time? possible?
No. I did not know "java date picker". Thank you very much, and I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Anyway check my [updated comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851351/add-datetime-with-calendar#comment38589481_24851351).

Comment: Maybe this will interest you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654342/is-there-any-good-and-free-date-and-time-picker-available-for-java-swing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JDatePicker from http://jdatepicker.org/.

It looks like [image]

There are some code snippets [How to use JDatePicker to display calendar component](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/how-to-use-jdatepicker-to-display-calendar-component), for example to create the picker shown above:

```
UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model);
JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel);

frame.add(datePicker);
```